# Point of tangency for a circle between two vector

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, circles

I'm having two vectors **p** and **q** starting at point **O** (origin). These vectors are known, as well as the origin point is. I know the angle **α** (alpha). Given a circle with arbitrary radius **r**, I want to be able to calculate point of tangency **X** (and ideally also **C**). I'm interested in a first solution, that fits in the angle. I just can't figure it out.

[image: Situation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle $\angle XOC$ is $\alpha/2$ as can be seen by symmetry. Hence $r = \lvert OC\rvert\cdot \sin (\alpha/2)$, and $\lvert OX\rvert = \lvert OC\rvert \cdot \cos (\alpha/2)$. Thus $\lvert OX\rvert = r\cdot \cot (\alpha/2)$, $\lvert OC\rvert = r\cdot \csc (\alpha/2)$.

---

After clarification of the used coordinate system in the comments, given the angles $\phi$ and $\psi$ between the positive $x$-axis and the two rays, where the point $X$ shall be on the ray with angle $\phi$, the opening $\alpha$ is the (absolute) difference $\lvert \psi -\phi\rvert$. The distance from $O$ is is calculated above, and the direction is given by $(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$, so the coordinates of $X$ are

$$(r\cot(\alpha/2)\cos\phi,\, r\cot(\alpha/2)\sin\phi),$$

and the coordinates of $C$ are

$$\left(r\frac{\cos ((\phi+\psi)/2)}{\sin(\alpha/2)},\, r\frac{\sin((\phi+\psi)/2)}{\sin(\alpha/2)}\right).$$

Unfortunately, I don't see how to reduce the calls to the trigonometric functions easily.

---

Assuming a Cartesian coordinate system with $O$ at the origin $(0,0)$, and $Q = (q_x,0)$ with $q_x > 0$, and $P = (p_x,p_y)$ with $p_x > 0,\; p_y > 0$, the symmetry gives us that the $x$-component of $C$'s coordinates is $\lvert OX\rvert$, and the $y$-component is of course $r$, so

$$C = (r\cot (\alpha/2), r).$$

We have $\lvert OX\rvert = r\cot (\alpha/2)$, and the direction is given by $(\cos \alpha, \sin\alpha)$, so

$$X = r\cot(\alpha/2)(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha),$$

and using $\cos\alpha = \cos^2 (\alpha/2) - \sin^2 (\alpha/2) = 1-2\sin^2(\alpha/2)$; $\sin\alpha = 2\sin(\alpha/2)\cos(\alpha/2)$, we obtain

$$\begin{gather}
\cot(\alpha/2)\cos\alpha = \cot(\alpha/2) - 2\cos(\alpha/2)\sin(\alpha/2) = \cot(\alpha/2) - \sin\alpha\\
\cot(\alpha/2)\sin\alpha = 2\cos^2(\alpha/2) = 1 + \cos\alpha
\end{gather}$$

whence

$$X = \bigl(r(\cot(\alpha/2) - \sin\alpha), r(1+\cos\alpha)\bigr).$$

Comment: That calculates only a distance. The distance itself seems to be OK though. Can you include the point as well. I'm asking because it will probably involve somehow additional trigonometric function(s). I'm programmer, so I'd like to be sure, there's no faster (lower number of trigonometric functions) solution when both distance, and point are calculated at once.

Comment: For the point itself, we must use some coordinates. Is it okay to assume Cartesian coordinates with $O$ the origin, and $q$ on the positive ray of the $x$-axis, and the $y$-component of $p$ positive?

Comment: Yes. p is a line (vector) from O[ox, oy] to P[px, py].

Comment: I've added coordinates. If your coordinate system is different, I hope you know how to rotate/reflect things to get the coordinates you need, otherwise, specify your coordinate system, then I can do it.

Comment: I've calculated it for the picture (roughly of course). In picture r=23, α=225° (0° being direction to east).. the X resulted in [39, 39]. That seems OK, but then I've tried it for α=45° that returned [39, 39] as well, but I'd expect on of them to be negative [-39, -39]. The system I'm using is standard 2D graphics. (On monitor) Left is -x, right is +x, top is -y, bottom is +y. I'd be able to accommodate for mirroring, but this returns +/+ values for opposite directions. It is possible, that I've miscalculated of course (always a possibility).

Comment: Oh, I've mixed up α with.. what? Oh, you've rotated the coordinates, or something. I've assumed you mean standard Cartesian coordinates (I'm not that good in English, so description of switching axis escaped me), this way the angle become unified. But the this is not an angle from axis in this light it is a range of angles. This way there are no solutions for other quadrants, as it is all reduced to only positive quadrant.

Comment: Wait. An angle of $180°$ or more does not determine a point $X$ or $C$ in that way. You can roll the circle along the one ray, over the centre of the angle, and then along the other ray. Your angle must be less than $180°$ in magnitude. And in the picture, you have an angle of $45°$ (plus/minus inaccuracies). "The system I'm using is standard 2D graphics." Urk. No known computer graphics system uses half-sane coordinates. Let me see if I can make sense of what  you describe.

Comment: "I've assumed you mean standard Cartesian coordinates" I did, but "standard" as in "standard for mathematicians", not the weird stuff computer graphics systems use ;)

Comment: But in Cartesian system, this would be angle of 225°, and X would be in x negative/y positive quadrant, but you rotated it, so it became non-standard, angle between p and x-axis become angle between p and y-axis, therefore it has only one solution. But I'm able to cope with whatever rotation, or mirroring, but I'm unable to cope with collapse to only one quadrant. So to find common language: 1) angle between p and q = 45°, between p and x-axis (horizontal) is 225° (east 0°, south 90°), left = -x, right = +x, top = -y, bottom = y (it starts at [0,0] top-left screen corner).

Comment: @SmartK8 Coming from different worlds, "standard" and "Cartesian system" mean different things for us, which makes communication somewhat harder. But we're off to a good start now. Yes, I took $\alpha$ to be the angle between the two rays. So if your angle is the angle between the one ray and the positive $x$-axis, you'd get the angle between the two rays by subtraction. If I got it right, your second ray would be at $270°$, so subtraction yields $225° - 270° = -45°$. Insert that into the formula, flip axes, you get $(39,-39)$, rotate, $(-39,-39)$. Let me edit.

Comment: I agree about the confusion, but screen space isn't that much different from Cartesian system, basically only y-axis is flipped. To explain the q is actually an obstacle (wall), p is a trajectory of the moving object, while O is a collision point. I can rotate and flip the coordinates, but there are simply two different angles involved. Let's call the other one Θ an angle between x-axis and p, this one is different from α (angle between p and q). Because q won't always align with axis (just a coincidence). Sorry, for confusion. I didn't expected to make it such a difference in pure math.

Comment: @SmartK8 It's not much difference in principle, it's just not easy (for me) to find the correct translation from my coordinates into yours. I'm still getting confused by the orientation flip.

Comment: Well, I've found how to do it, but it's too much trigonometry at once, but the distance calculation will do. Thank you.
  
  Θ = atan2(Py - Oy, Px - Ox);
  X = [Ox + |OX| * cos(Θ), Oy + |OX| * sin(Θ)]

Comment: I'm checking your edits, if it works it is better, because I can calculate rcot(α/2) only once, therefore it will require only 3 trigonometric functions to calculate X, that would be fantastic.

Comment: I've verified it, and it works great now. Thanks again.

Comment: 8-D Happy to help.